# import theano ,IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I try to install theano.Firstly,I download zip from github,then put the file in correct destination.When I try to import it,something wrong happen.
I use Anaconda prompt.

(E:\Anaconda) C:\Users\Administrator>python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org

> > > import theano
> > >       0
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "E:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\theano\theano__init__.py", line 68, in 
> > >           from theano.version import version as **version**
> > >         File "E:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\theano\theano\version.py", line 14, in 
> > >           int(short_version.split('.')[2])
> > >       IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might have downgraded your theano version instead of updating it (just like I did recently).

Try this in your notebook:

```
!pip uninstall -y theano
!conda install -y theano
```

Comment: I have installed successfully by using your way.Thank you~